# Set Quota on multiple folders from list

Tags: powershell, quota

We're trying to set quota on multiple folders, all user directories will have 0.5gb limit (hard limit)

I thought something simple as below, but keeps saying path is invalid, which it isn't :(

```
$shares = get-content c:\PSR\users.txt
foreach ($share in $shares)
{
New-FsrmQuota -Path "C:\test" -Description "limit usage to 0.5 GB" -Size 0.5GB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the paths correctly which you are taking from  text file.

Below code may work fine.

```
$shares = get-content c:\PSR\users.txt
foreach ($share in $shares)
{
New-FsrmQuota -Path $share  -Description "limit usage to 0.5 GB" -Size 0.5GB
}
```

Hope it HElps.